# Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS won't install, no errors shown

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

I have wasted nearly a day on this.

I have a fresh Windows Server 2012 R2, fully up to date, that I am trying to install IIS on.

I run the add Roles and Features wizard, select my required features, but the install fails without an error message.

[image]

I am unable to find any logs or details to help me trouble shoot what could be wrong.

Task Details shows me nothing:

[image]

Could someone please point me to somewhere that could explain my lack of success, or even better, let me know how to get IIS to install?

Comment: Win2012 R2 requier a liscence, that mean you paid for it. So you have to call Microsoft assistance, they will help you.

Comment: @Froggiz if it comes to that I suppose. As a developer, however, I must say that sounds way too much like social pressure. Reinstallation would be far less challenging ;)

Comment: Anything in C:\Windows\IIS.log or C:\Users\you\Appdata\Local\Temp\ServerManager.Log? Add Roles and Features is supposed to write there.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I have the same problem.

Comment: None of the previous answered helped me with the same situation however I was able to install IIS with powershell.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Could not get any information about what was wrong. However from [microsofts own guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831515.aspx) there is an option for installing through cmd with:

```
  Start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-Security;IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;IIS-ManagementConsole;WAS-WindowsActivationService;WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI
```

For whatever reason this worked while the wizard did not.

Comment: I get pkgmgr has been deprecated, use dism error

Answer (score 1):

I run into this error while trying to install Request Monitor feature of IIS. In order to troubleshoot it, I would recommend checking:

- CBS logs (C:\Windows\Logs\CBS)
- DISM logs (C:\Windows\Logs\DISM)
- ApplicationHost.config file (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config)
- The output of Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth command
- Procmon logs (Use Process Monitor tool)

In my case Procmon logs showed `PARSE_ERROR_INFO` while reading **applicationHost.config** file which was corrupted. Reinstalling IIS solved the issue. [0x800f0922 Update IIS-RequestMonitor of package IIS-WebServer-Core-Package failed](https://port135.com/2019/11/08/update-iis-requestmonitor-package-0x800f0922/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe trying to install IIS with PowerShell will give you a better error message:

Install-WindowsFeature Web-Server

Pascal

Comment: Did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem at work. The issue was caused by a Microsoft security update. Specifically KB's 3098779 and 3097997 both cause this behavior. Uninstalling these updates corrected the issue for me.

Here's the KB I used to resolve this issue.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118750